# Responsive UL list of images

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-lists, media-queries

Hi I am trying to make this UL responsive in a 1024x768 resolution.

This is the list:

```
<ul class="beforeafterpics">
    <li><img class="ba-bg" src="IMAGEHERE" width="220px" height="264px" alt="tummy tuck before and after pictures"></li>
    <li><img class="ba-bg" src="IMAGEHERE" width="220px" height="264px" alt="tummy tuck before and after pictures"></li>
    <li><img class="ba-bg" src="IMAGEHERE" width="220px" height="264px" alt="tummy tuck before and after pictures"></li>
    <li><img class="ba-bg" src="IMAGEHERE" width="220px" height="264px" alt="tummy tuck before and after pictures"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the original CSS:

```
.beforeafterpics {
    text-align: center;
}
.beforeafterpics li{
    display: inline-block; 
    list-style-type: none;
}
.ba-bg {background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
    padding: 4px;
}
```

and this is the media query:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    {
        .ba-bg {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

I want the pictures to be in two columns instead of four when the browser's resolution is 1024x768.

--- Got it to work! Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle out of this?

Comment: First of all media queries operate off width.  A resolution of 1024x768 means 1024px wide by 768px high.  You don't need the min-width 768px part of your media query, unless you want to target the viewport width of devices BETWEEN 768px wide and 1024px wide.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the img's with the media query but not the li's.

As the img's are contained by the li's your current media query is not working as expected.

You need to add the media query to the li's width

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {

    .beforeafterpics li{
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

[HERES THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/pubzr/)

I am not sure where your UL is situated in your page but for example sake I have used 100% for the UL width.

Also it is worth noting you are using `inline-block` for your li's. In order for them to sit next to each other using 50% width you need to fix the white-space issue that occurs using in-line blocks. In my example I have added:

```
.beforeafterpics {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

in order to correct this for the example.

For more info on the inline-block white space issue and different ways to correct it:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

The following should do that. If not, please make a fiddle so we can see what might be interfering. Add class names where appropriate.

```
li {
    width:25%
}    

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    li {
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original css float your li item left (Better for cross browser as well)

Original CSS:

```
.beforeafterpics li{float:left; display:block; list-style-type: none;}
```

Then in your media query clear the third list item to bring it down.

Media query css:

```
.beforeafterpics li:nth-child(3){clear:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your media query, like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .ba-bg {
        width: 50%;
    }
    li.nth-child(2):after {
        content:"\a"; white-space:pre; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize that I do not know how to limit the `Results` frame in jsFiddle to 1024px, so I cannot test, but the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/gfv4u/)